# Convert timestamp to interval in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to convert a timestamp to interval & expecting an out of hh:mm only.

My code is like below

```
SELECT  to_timestamp('2020-01-10 08:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi')::timestamp without time zone 
        at time zone 'Asia/Calcutta' 
        at time zone 'Etc/UTC'
```

Actual purpose of the code is change the time zone into utc for a given date time value.

Comment: interval of what? seconds? microseconds? days? years?

Comment: Try this way: `SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-01-13 10:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Calcutta' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';`

Comment: Interval is time/date difference and can thus not be a single time/date.  Your code works, but interval has nothing to do with it.  Maybe you need to rephrase your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are trying to get the timedifference (interval) between two timezones at a specific time.
This can be done like this for example:

```
SELECT  to_timestamp('2020-01-10 08:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi')::timestamp without time zone 
        at time zone 'Asia/Calcutta'
        -  
        to_timestamp('2020-01-10 08:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi')::timestamp without time zone 
        at time zone 'Etc/UTC'
```

This returns an interval = -05:30:00
You can of course convert it to hours and minutes with the to_char function, but that returns string, not interval.

Best regards,
Bjarni